# String pattern matching using unreliable data

Tags: neural-network, string-matching, fuzzy-search

I know that there are several threads about string pattern matching, but I feel like my circumstances are slightly different.

I have a list of user-entered claim numbers, each claim number is unique.  Each claim number can be in varying formats, it all depends on the user and how much of the actual full claim number they give us.  We don't know what the insurance carrier's claim format is, they won't share it with us.

Let's assume that our users have entered the following claim numbers

Insurance Carrier X claim numbers:
04756G215
04759Q696
04760G279
04760T844
00631F546
006G34549
006J73029

Insurance Carrier Y claim numbers:
000628948-014
01-VK4994-0
01-VW6183-4
01-WC20436
12082356
01VL0063-6
01WB16121
03-016298-2
03-165476-3
1000-66-0792
1000-66-3808
1000-67-8667
1000-68-1360
1000-68-1686
1000-68-8494
1000-69-5647
1000-69-6905

Insurance Carrier Z:
42RBB903752
444F09799
51RBB672507
51RBC153279
55RBB120866
55RBB339718

As you can see, different formats.  Also, I am certain that I can't rely on the user to enter the correct one, they often omit parts of it because that part may have some claim office code in it, we simply don't know.

Knowing this, I want to enter a claim number in a system that tells me which is the likely carrier that it belongs to

So 55RBB339719 would most likely give me carrier Z.

Are neural networks the way to go?  Fuzzy Logic?

UPDATE:
Here's a string pattern to match
51RAB435220

As you can see it's the same pattern (2 digits, 3 characters, 6 digits).

However, a user can enter RAB435220 because the first two digits may be insignificant, meaning that they may be a department code rather than being the actual claim numbers.  It's possible that only the last 6 digits are the significant ones.
What makes it difficult is that we don't know what the significant digits are.

Comment: If there's a dash in it, carrier Y, if there's an R,B or F in the first four characters then carrier Z, otherwise carrier X. That catches all of your test cases, doesn't it? *"We don't know what the insurance carrier's claim format is, they won't share it with us."* - what? why not?

Comment: Sometimes users omit the dashes because they are lazy and could care less.  Unfortunately these aren't users under our control.  We don't know the format because our carriers like to protect their little secrets even though we're an important vendor for them.  What I have there is a pretty small sampling, the point is that we don't know what our users are going to omit or include.

Comment: You should try algorithms for edit-distance (Levensthein) or sequence-alignment (Smith-waterman, Needleman-Wunsch), i am not certain which one fits best to your scenario. If your texts to search in are long: use approximate string matching (yet the latter approach will limit your mismatches to a fixed number of your choice).

Comment: I'm not sure that any distance type search or approximate search is really going to work here.  The digits can be completely different, however the pattern might be similar (three digits, three chars, 3 more digits).

Comment: Best update your example by adding such a scenario.

Comment: Added a different example and some more detail

Comment: This example is also easy to handle with alignment algorithms. e.g. `edit-distance("51RAB435220", "RAB435220") = 2`, `edit-distance("55RBB339719","55RBB339718") = 1`. Accepting the match with lowest distance would work in this case. Edit-Distance is not always the best similarity metric, but you can choose from many (e.g. [here](http://www.coli.uni-saarland.de/courses/LT1/2011/slides/stringmetrics.pdf))